# ASP.NET Web Config Write, Remove .ASPX and Ignore Filenames with periods.

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-config

I've written a simple rewrite rule so I can remove the .aspx from all my page paths.

That way if someone types in http://www.domain.com/Contact, they will be taken to the contact page rather than having to type in http://www.domain.com/contact.aspx.

The following rule works fine, except that if the file name contains a period. I don't want the rule to apply, because even thought I have a condition to negate when the url is a file or directory, this doesn't apply to handlers and other special files. To avoid this issue I'm negated the special files by adding a condition for each one, this is no longer worker however as there are quite a bit of special circumstances that this comes up and I don't want to have to write a new one for each special case.

Basically I just need to add a condition that when there is a period in the file name to negate it. Can anyone help? I'm not that good at regular expressions.

```
<rule name="RewriteASPX" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the match field:

```
<match url="^(.*/[^.]*)$" />
```

It should match all url's that don't have a '.' after the last '/'.